# User is still signed in after AuthenticationManager.SignOut()

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

When I sign out a user in a controller, `User.Identity.Authenticated` is still true on the returned view.

If I refresh the page again, then `User.Identity.Authenticated` is false

```
    // GET: /Account/SessionExpired
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult SessionExpired()
    {
        AuthenticationManager.SignOut();

        //Clear the session
        SessionHelper.Clear();

        return View();
    }
```

Is it normal?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is normal as the authorization is checked before the action executes. If you want to log out before that you have to do it before that, for example with a custom attribute

Comment: Thank you. Could you post an example.

Comment: Sure you can take a look at an old answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503032/where-to-use-controller-httpcontext/2503085#2503085 The principle is the same, you override the OnActionExecuting method and log out that is executed before the action method executes

Comment: How can I have access to my authenticationmanager inside the attribute?

Comment: You can try to clear the HttpContext.Current.User.Identity I think that should work too. For example: HttpContext.Current.User =
    new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(string.Empty), null);

Answer (score 0):

The standard MVC template in Visual Studio uses a [RedirectToAction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction(v=vs.118).aspx) to instead of returning a View. That way the browser is automatically redirected to for example the home/index action from a new request.

Answer (score 0):

```
 // GET: /Account/SessionExpired
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult SessionExpired()
    {
        AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

        //Clear the session
        SessionHelper.Clear();

        return View();
    }
```